# Issue while migrating Dhtmlxtabbar from 3.5 to 4.1.3

Tags: dhtmlx

I am updating dhtmlx from v3.5 to v4.1.3 and loading tabbar from ajax call and each tabbar is having different href urls. Previously only selected tab gets load(hitting the url) while doing tabbar.loadStruct but in v4.1.3 all the href urls of tabbar are gets hitting at once while loading tabbar.loadStruct.

Following is the my tabbar xml

```
<tabbar hrefmode="ajax-html">
    <row>
        <tab id="151" width='100px' height='17px'  selected="1" href="/domain/url1.action">Quick View</tab>
        <tab id="198" width='100px' height='17px' href="/domain/url2.action">Chart Status</tab>
        <tab id="159" width='100px' height='17px' href="/domain/url3.action">Blackline</tab>            
    </row>
</tabbar>
```

only selected first url(i.e /domain/url1.action) gets invoked first time in previous version, but in v4.1.3 all the tabbar's url gets invoked immediate after tabbar.loadStruct.

Can some help me to load only selected tabbar's url?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an official tutorial that should help you: http://www.dhtmlx.com/blog/loading-content-into-tabs-on-demand/